# Why does `display: table;` cause a pseudo padding in a div? (And why only when it is itself in a table?)

Tags: css

I have a `table.matrix` in a `div.matrix-wrapper`.
The whole thing shall be centered in a bigger `div`.

I only achieved this by adding `display: table; margin: 0 auto;` to the wrapper.
(Adding the auto margin to the table is not an option, because of the gray border.)

On its own, the result looks the way I expect. (left)
But when I place it within a table, It looks like the wrapper has a padding. (middle)
When I remove `display: table;` from the wrapper, the pseudo padding goes away,
but then the centering does not work anymore. (right)

[image]

(External links removed.)

Based on the answer given by Alohci, I added this simplified example:

[image]

```css
.green {
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid #0d0;
 }
 
 .red {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid red;
 }
 
 .blue {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  background-color: blue;
 }
 
table {
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-spacing: 5px;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
table td {
  border: 3px solid gray;
  color: gray;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<h2>plain boxes</h2>

<p>The red box wraps directly around the blue box with the yellow border.</p>

<div class="green">
  <div class="red">
    <p class="blue"></p>
  </div>
</div>


<h2>boxes in table</h2>

<p>The red box inherits border-spacing from the surrounding table.</p>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="green">
        <div class="red">
          <p class="blue"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>


<h2>plain table</h2>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>plain</td>
    <td>table</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Although all the information necessary to answer is provided in the question without having to follow the external links, your question would be much better if you put the code to reproduce the issue directly in a Stack Snippet here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`border-spacing` and `border-collapse` inherit. The wrapping table has

```
border-spacing: 2px;
border-collapse: separate;
```

applied to it through the user-agent stylesheet, so these values are inherited by your div.matrix-wrapper and have effect when it's given `display:table`.

To remove the "padding", just set the div.matrix-wrapper to `border-spacing: 0px`.

Comment: Ah, the C in CSS... I added `border-collapse: collapse;` to `.matrix-wrapper`.